# How to decorate Expression for Select?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a query that aggregates a dozen tables. It looks like this:

```
db.MyTable.Where(t=>...)
  .Select(t => new Model {
    Field1 = t.SomeTable.Field,
    Field2 = t.SomeTable2.Field
    ...and so on, about 30 fields}).ToList();
```

It does not work very quickly, the database loads significantly

The question is:
Often, some fields are not needed and some tables need not be aggregated.
I want to make a basic Expression and decorate it with the necessary fields. How to do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @itsme86 Not sure how that is particularly helpful?

Comment: 1) Enable trace to see generated query. 2) Run it by hands. 3) See the plan of execution. 4) Add indexes/optimize on demand. The database "load" often means index scans or even worse - full scans.

Comment: @AndrewG This isn't a trivial bit of code to write. You can do it manually but as you may know writing expressions by hand can be quite verbose. There are libraries to make this easier, but if possible, I would strongly recommend that you just write enough methods that get the information you require, one for each purpose.

Comment: @eocron I already did that and all indexes have already done

Comment: @DavidG What libraries can do this?

Comment: @AndrewG See the duplicate I've closed this against for an example on how the code looks. If you want a library, I think System.Linq.Dynamic will do it.